# Xamarin iOS WKWebView not showing google recaptcha

Tags: ios, xamarin, safari, mobile-safari, wkwebview

It's Xamarin iOS application, where I am opening a url in WKWebView which contains "Google reCAPTCHA" option. But it does not show captcha option in webview instead it keeps that place bank.

I tried opening same url in iPhone(Simulator) safari browser which produced the same result.

When I opened it on web browser i.e. Safari/Google chrome, it worked perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: I am very sorry for this. I can't provide you a url as it breaks client's policy.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for this.

There are two reasons why it wasn't working as expected :

1. My network was blocking re-captcha url.

   Solution - Solved this by connecting another network.
2. WKWebView has not calling decision handler for re-captcha url.

   Solution - Added condition where it executes decision handler in 
   DecidePolicy Method.

[Export("webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:")]

```
public void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        if (url.ToString().Contains("https://www.google.com/recaptcha"))  
         {
           decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
         }
    }
```